# Symfony Composer error when i try to lunch symfony

Tags: composer-php, phar

When I launch a symfony project I get this error, I have already deleted and installed the composer but nothing changes.

````
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PharException: internal corruption of phar "C:\Webtech\composer.phar" (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found) in C:\Webtech\composer.phar:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Webtech\composer.phar(28): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Webtech\composer.phar on line 28

Fatal error: Uncaught PharException: internal corruption of phar "C:\Webtech\composer.phar" (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found) in C:\Webtech\composer.phar:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Webtech\composer.phar(28): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Webtech\composer.phar on line 28```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP \_\_halt\_compiler not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719794/php-halt-compiler-not-found)

Comment: How did you reinstall Composer?

Comment: with https://getcomposer.org/download/